# Azure Cosmos DB Gremlin/Tinkerpop Token Auth with Java SDK

Tags: java, azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-gremlinapi

I'm trying to connect to a Gremlin collection in Azure Cosmos DB using a resource token. I adapted the documentation from here (it's for C# mainly): https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/how-to-use-resource-tokens-gremlin

The issue is that the date header of the token seems to be invalid once I try to access the data:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.concurrent.CompletionException: org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.exception.ResponseException: 

ActivityId : 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
ExceptionType : UnauthorizedException
ExceptionMessage :
    The input date header is invalid format. Please pass in RFC 1123 style date format.
    ActivityId: 755ab024-fc79-47a3-bc44-3231b2db7dc1, documentdb-dotnet-sdk/2.7.0 Host/64-bit MicrosoftWindowsNT/6.2.9200.0
Source : Microsoft.Azure.Documents.ClientThe input date header is invalid format. Please pass in RFC 1123 style date format.
ActivityId: 755ab024-fc79-47a3-bc44-3231b2db7dc1, documentdb-dotnet-sdk/2.7.0 Host/64-bit MicrosoftWindowsNT/6.2.9200.0
    BackendStatusCode : Unauthorized
    BackendActivityId : 755ab024-fc79-47a3-bc44-3231b2db7dc1
    HResult : 0x80131500
```

Anyone knows how to fix that? The JVM is set to GMT via `-Duser.timezone=GMT`

Here's the code. Please note that it's a Java CLI application just for testing connectivity. All data of the `cfg` is basically given by cli, method names should be self-explanatory.

Token generation, this is using the master key for the `DocumentClient` instance:

```
...
import com.microsoft.azure.documentdb.DocumentClient;
import com.microsoft.azure.documentdb.DocumentClientException;
import com.microsoft.azure.documentdb.FeedResponse;
import com.microsoft.azure.documentdb.Permission;
import com.microsoft.azure.documentdb.PermissionMode;
import com.microsoft.azure.documentdb.ResourceResponse;
import com.microsoft.azure.documentdb.User;
...

public class TokenGenerator {

    private String USER_ID = "demo-1";

    public String generateToken(CmdLineConfiguration cfg) throws DocumentClientException {
        try (DocumentClient client = Utilities.documentClientFrom(cfg)) {
            String databaseLink = String.format("/dbs/%s", cfg.getDatabaseId());
            String collectionLink = String.format("/dbs/%s/colls/%s", cfg.getDatabaseId(), cfg.getCollectionId());

            // get all users within database
            FeedResponse<User> queryResults = client.readUsers(databaseLink, null);
            List<User> onlineUsers = queryResults.getQueryIterable().toList();

            // if a user exists, grab the first one, if not create it
            User user;
            Optional<User> onlineUser = onlineUsers.stream().filter(u -> u.getId().equals(USER_ID)).findFirst();
            if (onlineUser.isPresent()) {
                user = onlineUser.get();
            } else {
                User u = new User();
                u.setId(USER_ID);
                ResourceResponse<User> generatedUser = client.createUser(databaseLink, u, null);
                user = generatedUser.getResource();
            }

            // read permissions, if existent use, else create
            FeedResponse<Permission> permissionResponse = client.readPermissions(user.getSelfLink(), null);
            List<Permission> onlinePermissions = permissionResponse.getQueryIterable().toList();
            Permission permission;
            if (onlinePermissions.size() == 0) {
                Permission p = new Permission();
                p.setPermissionMode(PermissionMode.Read);
                p.setId(USER_ID + "_READ");
                p.setResourceLink(collectionLink);
                ResourceResponse<Permission> generatedPermission = client.createPermission(user.getSelfLink(), p, null);
                permission = generatedPermission.getResource();
            } else {
                permission = onlinePermissions.get(0);
            }
            // return the token
            return permission.getToken();
        }
    }
}
```

Connect and query Gremlin:

```
...
import org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.AuthProperties;
import org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.AuthProperties.Property;
import org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.Client;
import org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.Cluster;
import org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.ResultSet;
...


        Cluster cluster;
        String collectionLink = String.format("/dbs/%s/colls/%s", cfg.getDatabaseId(), cfg.getCollectionId());
        TokenGenerator tg = new TokenGenerator();
        String token = tg.generateToken(cfg);

        Cluster.Builder builder = Cluster.build(new File("src/remote.yaml"));
        AuthProperties authenticationProperties = new AuthProperties();
        authenticationProperties.with(AuthProperties.Property.USERNAME, collectionLink);

        authenticationProperties.with(Property.PASSWORD, token);
        builder.authProperties(authenticationProperties);
        cluster = builder.create();

        Client client = cluster.connect();
        ResultSet results = client.submit("g.V().limit(1)");

        // the following call fails
        results.stream().forEach(System.out::println);

        client.close();
        cluster.close();
    }
```

`src/remote.yml`

```
hosts: [COSMOSNAME.gremlin.cosmosdb.azure.com]
port: 443
username: /dbs/DBNAME/colls/COLLECTIONNAME
connectionPool: { enableSsl: true}
serializer: { className: org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.ser.GraphSONMessageSerializerV2d0, config: { serializeResultToString: true }}
```

Comment: Hi,any updates here?Does my answer helps you?

Comment: Hi @jay-gong, thanks for your answer. Unfortunately I'm currently sick and not able to review it. Will do that once I've recovered.

Comment: Sure! Get well soon!

Comment: I raised this as Azure support ticket and they confirmed that there seems to be an issue. Hoping they'll provide a fix soon.

Comment: Fine,you could post updates here if you get it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With Azure Support I found out that the issue was a bug on Azure side. It occurres when using custom VNets together with Cosmos. Meanwhile Azure has fixed it and everything is working.

Answer (score 0):

I can't reproduce your issue on my side. I tried to extend this [cosmos graph demo](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/azure-cosmos-db-graph-java-getting-started/blob/master/src/GetStarted/Program.java) for java.In that demo,master key is used,so i followed your partial code and [official sample](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/how-to-use-resource-tokens-gremlin#use-a-resource-token) to access graph db with resource token.

Your code of connection with db seems working.My main class as below which is similar to yours:

```
import org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.*;
import org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.exception.ResponseException;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;


public class Program
{
        static final String gremlinQueries[] = new String[] {"g.V().limit(1)"};

  public static void main( String[] args ) throws ExecutionException, InterruptedException {

        String token = "***";
        Cluster cluster;
        Client client;

        try {
            Cluster.Builder builder = Cluster.build(new File("src/remote.yaml"));
//            Cluster.Builder builder = Cluster.build();
            AuthProperties authenticationProperties = new AuthProperties();
            authenticationProperties.with(AuthProperties.Property.USERNAME,
                    String.format("/dbs/%s/colls/%s", "db", "coll"));

// The format of the token is "type=resource&ver=1&sig=<base64 string>;<base64 string>;".
            authenticationProperties.with(AuthProperties.Property.PASSWORD, token);

            builder.authProperties(authenticationProperties);

            // Attempt to create the connection objects
            cluster = builder.create();
//            cluster = Cluster.build(new File("src/remote.yaml")).create();
            client = cluster.connect();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // Handle file errors.
            System.out.println("Couldn't find the configuration file.");
            e.printStackTrace();
            return;
        }

        // After connection is successful, run all the queries against the server.
        for (String query : gremlinQueries) {
            System.out.println("\nSubmitting this Gremlin query: " + query);

            // Submitting remote query to the server.
            ResultSet results = client.submit(query);

            CompletableFuture<List<Result>> completableFutureResults;
            CompletableFuture<Map<String, Object>> completableFutureStatusAttributes;
            List<Result> resultList;
            Map<String, Object> statusAttributes;

            try{
                completableFutureResults = results.all();
                completableFutureStatusAttributes = results.statusAttributes();
                resultList = completableFutureResults.get();
                statusAttributes = completableFutureStatusAttributes.get();            
            }
            catch(ExecutionException | InterruptedException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
                break;
            }
            catch(Exception e){
                ResponseException re = (ResponseException) e.getCause();

                // Response status codes. You can catch the 429 status code response and work on retry logic.
                System.out.println("Status code: " + re.getStatusAttributes().get().get("x-ms-status-code")); 
                System.out.println("Substatus code: " + re.getStatusAttributes().get().get("x-ms-substatus-code")); 

                // If error code is 429, this value will inform how many milliseconds you need to wait before retrying.
                System.out.println("Retry after (ms): " + re.getStatusAttributes().get().get("x-ms-retry-after"));

                // Total Request Units (RUs) charged for the operation, upon failure.
                System.out.println("Request charge: " + re.getStatusAttributes().get().get("x-ms-total-request-charge"));

                // ActivityId for server-side debugging
                System.out.println("ActivityId: " + re.getStatusAttributes().get().get("x-ms-activity-id"));
                throw(e);
            }

            for (Result result : resultList) {
                System.out.println("\nQuery result:");
                System.out.println(result.toString());
            }

            // Status code for successful query. Usually HTTP 200.
            System.out.println("Status: " + statusAttributes.get("x-ms-status-code").toString());

            // Total Request Units (RUs) charged for the operation, after a successful run.
            System.out.println("Total charge: " + statusAttributes.get("x-ms-total-request-charge").toString());
        }

        System.out.println("Demo complete!\n Press Enter key to continue...");
        try{
            System.in.read();
        } catch (IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            return;
        }

        // Properly close all opened clients and the cluster
        cluster.close();

        System.exit(0);
    }
}
```

The yaml file:

```
hosts: [***.gremlin.cosmosdb.azure.com]
port: 443
username: /dbs/db/colls/coll

connectionPool: {
  enableSsl: true}
serializer: { className: org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.ser.GraphSONMessageSerializerV2d0, config: { serializeResultToString: true }}
```

So,i'm afraid that root cause is generation of token.

> The input date header is invalid format. Please pass in RFC 1123 style
>   date format.

I searched this error message related to cosmos db and i found this [case](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/de4ad792-6b58-42e7-803c-4c6f549094c0/documentdb-java-example-errors) for your reference.It seems that the solution is changing local regional settings.You could trace the `x-ms-date` header of your request with Fiddler.

Comment: So I debugged the application, when requesting the permission via Azure Java SDK the `x-ms-date` headers are correctly sent. Within the Gremlin connection it is not used, I also do not know how I'd set it there.
Following Azure docs, the token on a permission updates once the permission is accesses. My code does not trigger that, I request the permission (and thus the token) via REST and got an updated token. Still, the RFC issue is present also with this token.